# extract bbcode atributte in several rows php

Tags: php

I have a string in php. It is in bbcode format.

I need to get an array of the values of a bbcode tag `[MSG][/MSG]`

`user1,2534,1232`

`user2,343425,4231`

`user3,234345,1423`

`user4,253434,123242`

`user5,251234,1652`

```
    $string ="
   [MSG='user1, comment: 253434, userid: 1232'] TEXT1[/MSG]

   [MSG='user2, comment: 343425, userid: 4231'] 
   TEXT2
   [/MSG]

   [MSG='user3, comment: 234345, userid: 1423']
    TEXT3
   [/MSG]
   [MSG='user4, comment: 253434, userid: 123242']
   TEXT4
   text 4
   text 4
   [/MSG]

   [MSG='user5, comment: 251234, userid: 1652'] TEXT5[/MSG]
  ";
```

This is what Ive done so far, but without success.

Im just focusing on this part `[MSG='userx, comment: x, userid: x']`

using the next regex but no success `[MSG='(.|n)*']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` to extract the data from the `MSG` tags, using this regex:

```
\[\s*MSG\s*=\s*'\s*([^,]+),\s+comment:\s+([^,]+),\s+userid: ([^']+)'\s*\]
```

which captures everything after the `'` until the first `,` in group 1; then everything after `comment:` until the next `,` in group 2 and everything after `userid:` until the closing `'` in group 3. In PHP:

```
preg_match_all("/\[\s*MSG\s*=\s*'\s*([^,]+),\s+comment:\s+([^,]+),\s+userid: ([^']+)'\s*\]/", $string, $matches);
foreach (array_keys($matches[0]) as $key) {
    echo "{$matches[1][$key]},{$matches[2][$key]},{$matches[3][$key]}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
user1,253434,1232
user2,343425,4231
user3,234345,1423
user4,253434,123242
user5,251234,1652
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OdA3b)

Comment: wow. I ended up making it but with a lot of explodes() lol, thank you. I think this is time to update my code.

Comment: @max this will hopefully be a bit easier to understand!